# Ubuntu Desktop Launcher behaving differently than in Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, launcher, ffplay

I run a small interactive script, that at its end, plays a very long video stream using ffplay. Since this is a very long video stream, the user usually closes the terminal windows that the script runs from.

The relevant part of the script looks like this:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

`import os`

`os.system('ffplay /home/rafa/tmp/1.mp4 &')`

When running from a Terminal, everything works fine. But the user wants an icon in the desktop, so I created a launcher that looks like this:

`[Desktop Entry]`

`Name=ff_launch`

`Exec=/home/rafa/tmp/7.py`

`Terminal=true`

`Type=Application`

The problem is that with that, the screen flicks for an instant and nothing happens. If don't send ffplay to background (meaning I remove the "&" from the script), a new window with the video stream is displayed, but if the terminal is closed, ffplay closes as well.

The script is interactive, meaning it asks the user for a few inputs before playing the video stream.

Any suggestion?